# What do you call the Ins/Del/Home/End/PageUp/PageDown key group on a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> can be called "functional keys", the numbered keys on the right of the keyboard are called the "numpad", and the arrows are called the "arrow keys".

Is there a common name for the following group of keys?

<kbd>Insert</kbd> <kbd>Delete</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>End</kbd> <kbd>Page Up</kbd> <kbd>Page Down</kbd>

Answer (score 33, accepted):

They are called the **navigation keys** and include:

<kbd>Insert</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Page Up</kbd>

<kbd>Delete</kbd> <kbd>End</kbd>  <kbd>Page Down</kbd>

[image]

Comment: is backspace also a navigation key ?

Comment: Why is this unsourced? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-your-keyboard-18b2efc1-9e32-ba5a-0896-676f9f3b994f

Comment: @MichaelBoies I would argue no… as it does move your cursor position but it also **modifies** the text content. (Ignoring the IMHO abuse of web browsers historically using this to “go back”)